# GZIPInputStream decompression did not work fine for the compressed data with length more than 532 bytes

Tags: java, compression

I have created compression and decompression using gZipInputStream in java
It works fine for small amount of data but if the data length after compression becomes greater thatn 532 then my decompression does not work fine.

Thanks
Bapi

Answer (score 5):

To reiterate what others have said:

- It is often the case that **str.length() != str.getBytes().length()**. Many operating systems use a variable-length encoding (like [UTF-8, UTF-16 or Windows-949](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html#charsets_unicode)).
- Use [OutputStream.close](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html#close()) methods to ensure that all data is written correctly.
- Use the return value of the [InputStream.read](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])) to see how many bytes have been read. There is no guarantee that all data will be read in one go.
- [Be careful](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_stringclass) when using the String class for encoding/decoding.

String compression/decompression methods

```
  private static byte[] compress(String str, Charset charset) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
      OutputStream deflater = new GZIPOutputStream(buffer);
      deflater.write(str.getBytes(charset));
      deflater.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    return buffer.toByteArray();
  }

  private static String decompress(byte[] data,
      Charset charset) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    try {
      InputStream inflater = new GZIPInputStream(in);
      byte[] bbuf = new byte[256];
      while (true) {
        int r = inflater.read(bbuf);
        if (r < 0) {
          break;
        }
        buffer.write(bbuf, 0, r);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    return new String(buffer.toByteArray(), charset);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (sb.length() < 10000) {
      sb.append("write the data here \u00A3");
    }
    String str = sb.toString();
    Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    byte[] compressed = compress(str, utf8);

    System.out.println("String len=" + str.length());
    System.out.println("Encoded len="
        + str.getBytes(utf8).length);
    System.out.println("Compressed len="
        + compressed.length);

    String decompressed = decompress(compressed, utf8);
    System.out.println(decompressed.equals(str));
  }
```

*(Note that because these are in-memory streams, I am not [being strict](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/10/java-how-not-to-make-mess-of-stream.html) about how I open or close them.)*

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a char encoding/decoding problem to me. One should use `Readers/Writers` to write Strings, e.g. `String.getBytes()`. Using `String(new byte[])` constructs are **not** the *proper* way..

You really should use a loop to read and check the returned **bytes read value** to ensure everything is read back!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use gCompress.close() not finish();

I also suggest that you cannot rely on str.length() being long enough to read.  There is a risk the data could be longer and so the String will be truncated.

You also ignore the return value of read().  read() is only guaranteed to read() one byte and is unlikely to read exactly str.length() bytes of data, so you are likely to have lots of trailing nul bytes \0. Instead you could expect to read str.getBytes().length()

Comment: Just about every line has a mistake - i ts a perfect example of how *NOT* to achieve the end goal.